# Draw the parallelogram spanned by the vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to figure out how to solve the following generic problem:

Draw the parallelogram spanned by the vectors $\begin{bmatrix} q \\ r \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} s \\ t \end{bmatrix}$.  The draw its image under the linear transformation defined by the following matrix: $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$

I have no idea how to solve this problem and I can't find any example in the book I got the problem from.  The only thing I can find that might help is:

Every linear function $L: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ has the form
$$
L \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ax + by \\ cx + dy \end{bmatrix} \quad\text{where}\quad A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
$$

but I don't really know how to apply this to the original problem.  Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Note** - the matrix $A$ in the generic problem and the matrix $A$ in the provided definition I found are unrelated

**EDIT 1** - Just from fooling around with some matrix multiplication I found that 2 of the points are given by
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} q \\ r \end{bmatrix} \quad\text{and}\quad \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} s \\ t \end{bmatrix}
$$
however, I can't figure out where the other 2 points come from.

**EDIT 2** - Here are example vectors with a known answer:

Matrices:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \,,\, \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \,,\, \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Solution:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \,,\, \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \,,\, \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \,,\, \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} 
$$

Comment: you don't want to pick some numbers for $a,b,c,\cdots?$

Comment: hint: if you "lock" the vectors to the origin, ie treat them as position vectors, then one point is (0,0), two others are (p,r) and (s,t), and the final one is where you would get to if you added the two vectors, ie (p+s, r+t)

Comment: Hey @abel, I'll make an edit with some numbers from a known answer.  I just wanted to get a generic answer to the problem so I can apply it to any problem and not just one.

Comment: for the transformation you can keep it generic as long as you're happy with matrix multiplication... the point (0,0) will transform to (0,0), (p,r) will transform to $(ap+br, cp+dr)$ etc